# regex, different ending string

Tags: php, regex

Im trying to match everything for the E) "column".

```
A1147/13 NOTAMN
Q) ESAA/QRRCH/IV/BO /AW/000/023/5933N01746E002
A) ESSA B) 1311140900 C) 1311211500
D) 14 21 0900-1500
E) UPPER LIMIT ES R16C KUNGSANGEN RAISED TO 2300 FT AMSL
REF AIP ENR 5.1
F) GND G) 2300FT AMSL
CREATED: 30 Oct 2013 10:00:00 
SOURCE: EUECYIYN
```

Using the following regex:

```
preg_match_all('/E\)(.*)(?=F\))/is', $string, $output);
```

I have managed to get the data, but only as long as the F) column exists, which it doesnt always do. Sometimes it ends just like:

```
A1147/13 NOTAMN
Q) ESAA/QRRCH/IV/BO /AW/000/023/5933N01746E002
A) ESSA B) 1311140900 C) 1311211500
D) 14 21 0900-1500
E) UPPER LIMIT ES R16C KUNGSANGEN RAISED TO 2300 FT AMSL
REF AIP ENR 5.1
CREATED: 30 Oct 2013 10:00:00 
SOURCE: EUECYIYN
```

How to solve this?

---

Edit:
This is the part that i want to return:

```
UPPER LIMIT ES R16C KUNGSANGEN RAISED TO 2300 FT AMSL
REF AIP ENR 5.1
```

It will either end with the start of column F) or the text CREATED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using HamZa's method, with a little other tweak:

```
E\)(.*?)(?=F\)|$)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/zA9dE9)

You might also try something like this, though it can be a little longer to process:

```
E\)((?:(?!F\)).)+)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/hL1qR0)

`(?:(?!F\)).)+` will match anything except `F)`

If you want to match until `CREATED:`, you can easily add it to the regex:

```
E\)((?:(?!F\)|CREATED:).)+)
```

Comment: The last part solved it! Great demo site, i didn't know about that one! :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use DOTALL and use MULTILINE:

```
/^E\).*$/im
```

Comment: @HamZa: It did work in your demo by matching: `E) UPPER LIMIT ES R16C KUNGSANGEN RAISED TO 2300 FT AMSL`

Comment: Hmmm it's not clear in the question, but I interpreted it as to match until `SOURCE: EUECYIYN` -- I could be wrong

Comment: @HamZa: I may be wrong but as per `Im trying to match everything for the E) "column".` I interpreted as full line starting from `E)`